# Replace [ ] brackets in NSString?

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa, nsstring

I'm trying to find and replace any occurrence of `[URL]` in an `NSString`. This is my approach:

```
NSString *test = @"Test [URL] 123";
test = [test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[URL]"
                                       withString:@"HERE"
                                          options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                            range:NSMakeRange(0, test.length)];
```

The result of this is `Test [HEREHEREHERE] 123`.
I guess it's because `[URL]` means any of those 3 characters, so all 3 characters will be replaced with `HERE` one after another.

However I also tried `\[URL\]` with the same result.

So, how do I actually search for the characters `[` and `]`?

Comment: Can you define your problem better? If you want to literally replace the string `@"[URL]"` then why are you using a regular expression?

Comment: Because later it will be something like `[URL=http:/some.url.com]`.

Comment: Ok, then can you fully define what you're trying to match? When writing regular expressions you really need to define your problem correctly, or you're going to have edge cases that don't work.

Comment: I'll replace `[URL=http://any.url.com]text[/URL]` with just the content between the URL tags and link it to the URL specified. Just like discussion boards do. I'll be able to do that now. I just didn't realize that in Cocoa I needed to escape the brackets twice, as @dasblinkenlight pointed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are absolutely right about diagnosing your problem: the square brackets are meta-characters in the regular expression language, so they get interpreted by the regex engine.

You need to double-escape your slashes, because they are special characters in both Objective-C and regexp language: `@"\\[URL\\]"`

Comment: (That is, the regular expression engine "sees" `\[URL\]`.)

Answer (score 1):

try instead

```
test = [test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\[URL\\]"
                                       withString:@"HERE"
                                          options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                            range:NSMakeRange(0, test.length)];
```

hope it helps:)